# TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using typescript in a web project. I use `awesome-typescript-loader` as a `webpack` loader. I am getting error when building my project:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:82:15 
    TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:85:15 
    TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/util.d.ts:7:15 
    TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/ts3.2/util.d.ts:10:15 
    TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'.
```

I initiated a complete new folder with just `typescript` and `@types/typescript` installed, I can still see the same error complained by `visual studio code`.

Versions below:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^11.13.6",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4"
  }
```

As the error showed above, I found

in `index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "util" {
    namespace inspect {
        const custom: symbol;
    }
    namespace promisify {
        const custom: symbol;
    }
    namespace types {
        function isBigInt64Array(value: any): boolean;
        function isBigUint64Array(value: any): boolean;
    }
}
```

in `util.d.ts`:

```
declare module "util" {
    namespace inspect {
        const custom: unique symbol;
    }
    namespace promisify {
        const custom: unique symbol;
    }
    namespace types {
        function isBigInt64Array(value: any): value is BigInt64Array;
        function isBigUint64Array(value: any): value is BigUint64Array;
    }
}
```

We can see `custom` is indeed being re-declared in `index.d.ts` and `util.d.ts`.

So my question is how to fix this issue? Is this a bug of @types/node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Removing reference to node in tsconfig fixed the issue for me.

Sample tsconfig.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
     // "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2017"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Also be sure to look for and try removing any of these: `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I accidentally **included** *node_modules/@types*. Fixed by comment it out like this:

```
"include": ["src/**/*.ts","__tests__/**/*.ts"/*, "node_modules/@types"*/]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the error message was misleading just because of something wrong cached. I tried many things, but finally solved it by removing npm_modules, clearing cache, and new installation:

```
npm cache clean --force 
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this piece of code twice in protractor.conf.js file

```
require('ts-node').register({
    project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
 });
```